# Checkout page validation not working in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I have added custom text field for bank transfer method.

**In template file:**

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" />
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
    <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
    <fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items allbank ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}">
    <div class="field _required">
        <label data-bind="attr: {for: getCode() + '_bankowner'}" class="label">
            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Account Owner'--><!-- /ko --></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input data-validate="{'required-entry':true}" type="text" name="payment[bankowner]" class="input-text" value=""
                   data-bind="attr: {
                                    id: getCode() + '_bankowner',
                                    title: $t('Account Owner'),
                                    'data-container': getCode() + '-bankowner',
                                    'data-validate': JSON.stringify({'required':true})},
                                    valueUpdate: 'keyup' "/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>      
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {'title': $t('Place Order')},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**In js:**

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'jquery'
    ],
    function (ko, Component,$) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Ibnab_Additional/payment/banktransfer'
            },
            getData: function() {
                return {
                    'method': this.item.method,
                    'additional_data': {
                        'bankowner': $('#banktransfer_bankowner').val()
                    }
                };
            },
            /**
             * Get value of instruction field.
             * @returns {String}
             */
            getInstructions: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
            }
        });
    }
);
```

But the validation is not working .

How to validate field set when clicking place order button.

Ideas welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below updates to get validate your custom payment module's field.

**step 1)** Update the **template file** to add a `<form> </form>` tag between the fields you want to validate as given below.

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" />
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
    <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
   <form class="form" data-bind="attr: {id: getCode() + '-form'}" method="post" action="#">
    <fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items allbank ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}">
    <div class="field _required">
        <label data-bind="attr: {for: getCode() + '_bankowner'}" class="label">
            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Account Owner'--><!-- /ko --></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input data-validate="{'required-entry':true}" type="text" name="payment[bankowner]" class="input-text" value=""
                   data-bind="attr: {
                                    id: getCode() + '_bankowner',
                                    title: $t('Account Owner'),
                                    'data-container': getCode() + '-bankowner',
                                    'data-validate': JSON.stringify({'required':true})},
                                    valueUpdate: 'keyup' "/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
   </form> 
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>      
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {'title': $t('Place Order')},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**step 2)** Update **js** file to add function "validate" as given below.

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'jquery'
    ],
    function (ko, Component,$) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                 template: 'Ibnab_Additional/payment/banktransfer'
            },
       validate: function () {
                var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
                return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
            },
            getData: function() {
                return {
                    'method': this.item.method,
                    'additional_data': {
                        'bankowner': $('#banktransfer_bankowner').val()
                    }
                };
            },
            /**
             * Get value of instruction field.
             * @returns {String}
             */
            getInstructions: function () {
 return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**step 3)** Clean Static Content and cache

```
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/generated
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

[image]