# Checkout Validation and Place Order

Tags: magento2

[Checkout page validation not working in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255994/checkout-page-validation-not-working-in-magento2)

As per the above link i am gettting the validations and when place order getting the following Fatal error with loading screen and order was not placing.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function appendChild() on null in /var/www/html/retailfly/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/src/Emogrifier.php:1419
```

Comment: can you post code for emogrifier

Comment: It is a core file and we not changed any core related.

Comment: I tried removing the validation for bank transfer but still the issues is there so i think Installing this Ibnab_Additional module for bank transfer payment method we are getting the issue for placing order.

Comment: yeah maybe remove that one first and check if error still exist otherwise it is the one causing the issue

Comment: Disabled module but still getting error with loading icon after placed order.
And in console we are getting the following error:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More] error-processor.js:28:25

Comment: @magefms, same error, i have not installed any emogrifier  module,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please run the following command:

```
composer require pelago/emogrifier:2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to a syntax error in your email template. Please check the email template that you recently edited, and find for a `Syntax` error. Emogrifier already exists that is why it's also telling you the `line number` which is throwing this exception.

If you further extend your PHP error, in your `web server logs`, you will also see other errors such as CSS or etc.

**Syntax Error:**
*A syntax error is an error in the source code of a program. Since computer programs must follow strict syntax to compile correctly, any aspects of the code that do not conform to the syntax of the programming language will produce a syntax error.*